# mechanism apart from locking(spin lock, sempahore) for Synchronization

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, operating-system, synchronization, locking

I know for synchronization in c there are several mechanism like spin lock, semaphore, seq_lock, conditional variable etc each has it's pros and cons and when to use which is depend on situation.

But every synchronization mechanism above add some extra processing to the program.

This is an interview question "Is there any other way apart from locking for Synchronization". I said we can use Barriers or our own wait_queue but this might be useful is only some situation not in some may be in 1 or 2.

So is there any mechanism apart from locking(spin lock, semaphore) for Synchronization ?

Answer (score 0):

Locking is expensive in the kernel. In addition to the above you have RCU: Read-Copy-Update which separates update and reclaimation information, where both readers and writers can avoid locking altogether.

Its not an complete alternative to the above as it depends on what you are trying to serialize. You could also consider using per-cpu data structures and avoid global expensive locks, this still requires synchronizing with the ISR's while preemption must be disabled. Forgot to add atomic operations on bits and integers.

Comment: yes it seems correct but again it's cannot always be used as alternative of Locking.

Comment: Each of the synchronization mechanism used depends problem in question trying to address.

Comment: do u think it's complete solution ? Like locking mechanism can be used in any situation when we want synchronization.